# Error with Liferay upgrade from 7.1.3-ga4 t0 7.2.1-ga2

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

We are currently working with liferay-ce-portal-7.1.3-ga4 and we want to upgrade it to liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2, for this we are making the process as described here https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/installation-and-upgrades/upgrading-liferay/upgrade-basics/using-the-database-upgrade-tool.html, but the db_upgrade script logs shows us the following:

```
ERROR [main][LPKGDeployerRegistrar:230] Unable to track installed app Liferay CE Foundation - Liferay CE Portal Portlet Bridge - Impl with Marketplace
com.liferay.marketplace.exception.NoSuchModuleException: No Module exists with the primary key 85626
        at com.liferay.marketplace.service.persistence.impl.ModulePersistenceImpl.remove(ModulePersistenceImpl.java:3638)
        at com.liferay.marketplace.service.persistence.impl.ModulePersistenceImpl.remove(ModulePersistenceImpl.java:3614)
        at com.liferay.marketplace.service.base.ModuleLocalServiceBaseImpl.deleteModule(ModuleLocalServiceBaseImpl.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:50)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:69)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopInvocationHandler.invoke(AopInvocationHandler.java:49)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy406.deleteModule(Unknown Source)
        at com.liferay.marketplace.internal.lpkg.deployer.LPKGDeployerRegistrar._doRegister(LPKGDeployerRegistrar.java:212)
        at com.liferay.marketplace.internal.lpkg.deployer.LPKGDeployerRegistrar._register(LPKGDeployerRegistrar.java:227)
        at com.liferay.marketplace.internal.lpkg.deployer.LPKGDeployerRegistrar.activate(LPKGDeployerRegistrar.java:92)
.
.
.
.
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:891)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:469)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:1004)
        at com.liferay.registry.internal.RegistryImpl.registerService(RegistryImpl.java:374)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader._registerModuleServiceLifecycle(DBUpgrader.java:436)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.main(DBUpgrader.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.db.upgrade.client.DBUpgraderLauncher.main(DBUpgraderLauncher.java:55)
```

This exception is repeated with different Apps, but the process finishes, anyway when we want to start the new liferay instance it fails.

As the errors are with some apps I decided to try to update the apps from the marketplace, but just 2 apps are there to upadte and these from Liferay CE Foundation are not, is addition if you see here https://web.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/71924489 it appears this app was not updated anymore, then I decided to try to delete them via the marketplace, but it didn't work, after this I decided (very bad idea) to delete the lpkg files from the /osgi/marketplace folder and of course the Liferay didn't work at all anymore and the upgrade also not.

What would be an option to make the upgrade? How could I solve the problems of the upgrade script (I think these problems are the source of the not working Liferay 7.1 afterwards)

Maybe is important to mention that we were using Liferay 6.2 before and we made the migration to 7.1 before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not really a solution to upgrade to version 7.2, it is a solution to upgrade in general.
We decided to migrate to version 7.3.7-ga8 and in this version the migration script and the process worked without any problem. It is worth mentioning that in Liferay 7.1 we used Postgres 9.6, for the migration we ran the script in this version of the db and then we generated a backup to restore it in version 11 which is required by Liferay 7.3